# C# winApi - getting registry last write date

Tags: c#, winapi, dllimport

My goal is to get last write time of the certain register.
To get value of register im using:

```
RegistryKey mKey;
//...
mKey.GetValue("SomeRegName");
```

And thats fine since everything is set properly for `mKey`.
I find out that i need to use this to get last writing time:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegQueryInfoKey", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
    extern private static int RegQueryInfoKey(
        UIntPtr hkey,
        out StringBuilder lpClass,
        ref uint lpcbClass,
        IntPtr lpReserved,
        out uint lpcSubKeys,
        out uint lpcbMaxSubKeyLen,
        out uint lpcbMaxClassLen,
        out uint lpcValues,
        out uint lpcbMaxValueNameLen,
        out uint lpcbMaxValueLen,
        out uint lpcbSecurityDescriptor,
        IntPtr lpftLastWriteTime);
```

So i need a handle to my key but i cant do it like that:

```
UIntPtr hkey = new UIntPtr(mKey.Handle);
UIntPtr hkey = (UIntPtr)mKey.Handle;
```

Because `SafeRegistryHandle` cannot be converted to `UIntPtr`. My Question is how should i call this winapi function to get what i need?
And second question is how i can convert `IntPtr lpftLastWriteTime` to `DateTime`?

Comment: You'd use var hkey = mKey.Handle.DangerousGetHandle();  If you don't like dangerous then simply declare the argument as SafeRegistryHandle as well.  Your pinvoke declaration needs work btw, lpClass is not *out* and the last argument is *out long*.  And using *int* instead of uint will make your life a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the declaration of `RegQueryInfoKey` replace

```
UIntPtr hkey
```

with

```
SafeRegistryHandle handle
```

and pass `mKey.Handle`.

As for the file time, don't pass that as `IntPtr`. Instead use the `FILETIME` structure.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct FILETIME {
    public uint DateTimeLow;
    public uint DateTimeHigh;
}
```

And declare that parameter like this:

```
out FILETIME lpftLastWriteTime
```

Or as Hans helpfully comments, use `long`

```
out long lpftLastWriteTime
```

which can then be passed directly to

```
DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc()
```

Some other comments:

- The registry functions do not call `SetLastError`.
- Setting `EntryPoint` is a little pointless.
- The second parameter should be `StringBuilder lpClass`.

I guess you've started from the declaration from pinvoke.net. Sadly these are frequently of poor quality.

Comment: Using *long* is better, that can simply be passed to DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc().

Comment: Yes it's pinvoke.net declaration. I was thinking that they done it well. Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0):

## Here is a full implementation:

### MSDN Helpful Links :

Base MSDN Link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx

Change msXXXXX number in the base link.

1. ms724284 - FILETIME structure
2. ms724897 - RegOpenKeyEx
3. ms724837 - RegCloseKey
4. ms724902 - RegQueryInfoKey
5. ms724205 - "Other way to convert FILETIME - Changing a File Time to the Current Time"

### The Code:

*The Code Includes WinAPI Methods Signatures (from PInvoke.net)*

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using FILETIME = System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME;

namespace RegistryUtils
{
    public static class RegistryHelper
    {

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "RegQueryInfoKey", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int RegQueryInfoKey(
            UIntPtr hkey,
            out StringBuilder lpClass,
            ref uint lpcbClass,
            IntPtr lpReserved,
            out uint lpcSubKeys,
            out uint lpcbMaxSubKeyLen,
            out uint lpcbMaxClassLen,
            out uint lpcValues,
            out uint lpcbMaxValueNameLen,
            out uint lpcbMaxValueLen,
            out uint lpcbSecurityDescriptor,
            ref FILETIME lpftLastWriteTime);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int RegCloseKey(UIntPtr hKey);


        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int RegOpenKeyEx(
          UIntPtr hKey,
          string subKey,
          int ulOptions,
          int samDesired,
          out UIntPtr hkResult);

        private static DateTime ToDateTime(FILETIME ft)
        {
            IntPtr buf = IntPtr.Zero;
            try
            {
                long[] longArray = new long[1];
                int cb = Marshal.SizeOf(ft);
                buf = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cb);
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(ft, buf, false);
                Marshal.Copy(buf, longArray, 0, 1);
                return DateTime.FromFileTime(longArray[0]);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (buf != IntPtr.Zero) Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buf);
            }
        }

        public static DateTime? GetDateModified(RegistryHive registryHive, string path)
        {
            var lastModified = new FILETIME();
            var lpcbClass = new uint();
            var lpReserved = new IntPtr();
            UIntPtr key = UIntPtr.Zero;

            try
            {
                try
                {
                    var hive = new UIntPtr(unchecked((uint)registryHive));
                    if (RegOpenKeyEx(hive, path, 0, (int)RegistryRights.ReadKey, out key) != 0)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                    uint lpcbSubKeys;
                    uint lpcbMaxKeyLen;
                    uint lpcbMaxClassLen;
                    uint lpcValues;
                    uint maxValueName;
                    uint maxValueLen;
                    uint securityDescriptor;
                    StringBuilder sb;
                    if (RegQueryInfoKey(
                                 key,
                                 out sb,
                                 ref lpcbClass,
                                 lpReserved,
                                 out lpcbSubKeys,
                                 out lpcbMaxKeyLen,
                                 out lpcbMaxClassLen,
                                 out lpcValues,
                                 out maxValueName,
                                 out maxValueLen,
                                 out securityDescriptor,
                                 ref lastModified) != 0)
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                    var result = ToDateTime(lastModified);
                    return result;
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (key != UIntPtr.Zero)
                        RegCloseKey(key);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

### Usage - Console Application

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using RegistryUtils;

namespace ConsoleApplicationRegistry
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dateModified = RegistryHelper.GetDateModified(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, @"SYSTEM\Software\Microsoft");
            if(dateModified.HasValue)
                Console.WriteLine("Key Last Modified Date: {0}", dateModified.Value);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Error... Try again.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To access a 64-bit key, modify the line where RegOpenKeyEx is called to: if (RegOpenKeyEx(hive, path, 0, (int)RegistryRights.ReadKey | (int)RegistryView.Registry64, out key) != 0)